# Put tags into a .html documents with command in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, putty

I'm trying to place an HTML tag at the beginning and end of an empty HTML file in Linux but can't figure out the commands. I think it needs to be some sort of command grouping? Can anybody help?

Comment: build your file up with a command group, i.e. `{echo "<H>" ; cat myHtml ; echo "</H>" ; } > myNewHTML`. GOod luck.

Comment: thanks, I used the >> operator to append to the end of a file, in addition to command grouping, like this: ( echo "<html>" > foo.html ; echo "</html>" >> foo.html )

Comment: arg, I missed that your file was empty. Just do `printf "<H>\n</H>\n" > file`. Less is more ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that worked for this was the following command grouping:

```
( echo "<html>" > foo.html ; echo "</html>" >> foo.html )
```

Using the >> operator to ensure the end tag goes at the bottom.
Cheers

Comment: or more succintly, use `echo -e "<html>\n</html>" > foo.txt`